# Monthly Report on Tax Invoice (Included & Separated) by Supplier internal tax invoice number and report print from date range

Tags: ms-access

I have created forms with goods-in-head and goods-in-detail as its sub form to record all merchandise goods for my store. For simplicity I state structure is as follows:

Goods-in-head form

1. date
2. supplier id
3. Value Added Tax "included" in its cost price or "later added" into its cost
4. supplier document id that they use to call these tax invoice they gave me
5. goods-in-head id

Goods-in-detail subform
(I use goods-in-head id as its parent id, and extract data from product table)

1. goods-in-detail (from goods-in-head id)
2. product id
3. product name (from product table)
4. product quantity bought
5. cost of product bought by unit
6. product unit count (from product table)
   I created "fields" on the subform in order to create "calculation" for each product rows as well as to make total summation of everything bought on each goods-in-head id.

Now, I must create a form where I could "select" a bunch of goods-in-head grand total from a certain period of time from- and to-. The problem is ...

I have tried to create query report where I "calculated" each row exactly like what I did in "detail subform in my goods-in-head form" as well as extract value added tax with condition in case they are "included" in the goods price or "excluded" ... However, when I open the report, it seems to show me everything from the beginning that I have started recording my purchase since 5 years ago!

I tried group&sort but they only seems to "split" each rows from each other... and "split" form doesn't seem to give the calculation...

Here is what my current report has given me for example...

No.   Date     Bill No.    Supplier Name        Supplier Tax ID      Amount    TaxType   VatAmount

1    1/12/2016   A11          A                    1111111111111      700       Excluded   49

2    1/12/2016   A11          A                    1111111111111      100       Excluded   7

3    1/12/2016   B11          B                    1111111111111      200       Excluded   14

4    1/12/2016   B11          B                    1111111111111      200       Excluded   14

5    1/12/2016   B11          B                    1111111111111      200       Excluded   14

6    1/12/2016   C11          C                    1111111111111      100       Included   6.54

7    1/12/2016   C11          C                    1111111111111      100       Included   6.54

8    1/12/2016   C11          C                    1111111111111      100       Included   6.54

Sum  Error       Sum Error

As you can see, even in the same month,
you can see report gave me "each rows" in the "detail of goods-in"

Here is what I need...
No.   Date     Bill No.    Supplier Name        Supplier Tax ID      Amount    TaxType   VatAmount

1    1/12/2016   A11          A                    1111111111111      800       Excluded   56

2    1/12/2016   B11          B                    1111111111111      600       Excluded   42

3    1/12/2016   C11          C                    1111111111111      300       Included   19.62

Sum    1700     Sum 117.62

How could I "merge" each row of the details for each products into "one grand total of each bills issued by my supplier?" so that each rows could only represent "one bill no." and its "total amount of that entire one bill" together with its "total amount of the tax worth from that bill?"

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possibly base report on an aggregate query. Or use report Sorting & Grouping with aggregate calc in footer. Question is about report design, not programming and therefore is not appropriate for SO. There is no code to analyze.

Comment: I couldn't follow the question

Comment: I apologize for my misleading question which cause you being unable to follow my question. By the way, hear June7, I tried Group by on my query and receive the sum for each "date" of my invoice now, however, I do understand that we could use query to extract data we need. Currently, I have been working on user interfere to allow my family members to use the front end to extract basic report from the software. For example, allow them to choose date from a form and "Search" to show sales from June 3 2021 to June 10 2021 to see what we had just received our supplies and print.Thank you very much!